# Apache Cordova Visual Studio - 404 Error on New Project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017

I wanted to start using Apache Cordova, so I installed it on my existing Visual Studio 2017 Community install. I created a new Cordova Blank Project. Clicked Start in Browser. In the build I get the following error:

```
SIM WARNING: Preparing platform 'android' failed: Source directory does not exist: D:\Home\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\platforms\android\platform_www
```

The app runs and seems to be working, but then even if I make changes to the "index.html" page, there's no difference in the app. It's always the default "DEVICE IS READY".

While it's debugging it says:

```
ERR_404 Resource not found: cordova_plugins.js
ERR_404 Resource not found: favicon.ico
```

I've tried including a blank cordova_plugins.js file and favicon.ico,
but it still gives the same error.

I've downloaded a few sample projects, but in each sample project it gives the same error message and shows the default Cordova Blank App, even though all of the code is different. The only thing that's different between the apps are their name.

I've never used Cordova and this has not been the best introduction... Please help.

### Update

Using NPM, I installed cordova separately from Visual Studio Built-in one.

This works perfectly fine and I'm able to change anything and it always reflects the changes when I run it. I believe it's because the Cordova version being used by Visual Studio is 6.3.1 and the one I installed via NPM is 7.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this error by adding this link:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
```

you can try with this too:

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:,">
```

Hope this helps.